# iOS 7 iAds backwards compatibility

Tags: ios, iad, backwards-compatibility

With iOS 7 iAd integration should be easier than ever. Adding the framework and a setting aproperty. But what I can't decipher is, will this work on devices running iOS versions 5 and 6?

What do I need to do if I want my app to show iAds on iOS 5+6+7?

Comment: iAds has been supported since iOS version 4, base code for the banner is the same see Doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html). I've been using iAds with the same code for iOS 6 to 7 without any problems

Comment: Are you facing issues on iOS5 or 6?

Comment: No I have not started the implementation, but from the documentation I could no see if the new simple method would only work in iOS7. I need it ti work all the way back to iOS5. But sounds like it should work then.